# Jetty does not serve static SVGZ files with correct content type

Tags: jetty

I added the extension svgz to serve compressed svg files, but jetty issues the wrong content encoding. I believe it should be a gzip encoding.

Does anyone know how to configure Jetty to serve static SVGZ files? This is pretty important, as these files are typically very large in size before compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files with extension SVGZ are just SVG files compressed with GZip compression.
Rename the file extension, if the file is `logo.svgz` rename it to `logo.svg.gz` but keep it compressed.

When compressed SVG files are sent from a Web Server, there are 2 pieces of information that should be in the response headers.

```
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Typically, a MIME Type mapping is established in the `${jetty.home}/etc/webdefault.xml` file  (look for `<mime-mapping>`) for the `DefaultServlet` to use to serve this static file with the appropriate Content-Type, however, this is also compressed, so that means all of the Gzip logic should kick in.

The DefaultServlet will set the appropriate `Content-Encoding` header if it sees a .gz file extension present for the file requested.

In other words, your http client (browser) can request the file `logo.svg`, but DefaultServlet will serve from the file contents from `logo.svg.gz` with `Content-Encoding` set to gzip.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that, probably because it's ingenious. That works really great, thanks so much. One of my biggest files went from 250k to 66k. Amazing how easy that was, but surprising how little information was available through Google.